# Socket connection from chrome extension being blocked by proxy/firewall

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a web app in javascript that connects to a socket using socket.io and a Chrome Extension which connects in the same way and to the same server.
Everything works fine in most computers and internet connections, but one of my customer's computer is failing to have the Chrome Extension connected (the web app connects successfully).

By inspecting the extension's console for background.js (the script within the extension creating the socket connection) I see that it is not trying to connect to the right URL (my socket server) but to an unknown URL which seems to be a proxy: https://gateway.zscloud.net/auT?origurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmy_socket_server_domain...

Since this is happening only in that specific computer (from the 10 or so that I have tried with so far) using different internet connections (corporate network, guests network, mobile hotspot) and since other computers in those same networks DID succeed in connecting, I assume something installed or configured in the problematic computer is catching the connection request before it happens and tries to redirect it through a proxy.

Again, this happens only in the context of the Chrome Extension. The very same computer using the same internet connection DOES succeed in connecting from a web page in the same browser (Google Chrome).

Does anybody know what the problem could be? The client is not aware of having a security software (firewall, antivirus, etc...) that could be causing this, but it's a computer managed by his company so an admin could have done that for him. If that was the case, however, shouldn't the connection from the webpage be captured too? Is there anything specific to socket connections in Chrome Extensions that differ from regular web apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket connections differ from normal HTTP requests; they require a protocol upgrade after establishing that (some!) proxies may be unable to support.

I was at some point behind one such (transparent) proxy at work; however, it does not attempt to intercept HTTPS, which means I could use `wss:` WebSockets but not `ws:` WebSockets.

..which you should be using, anyway! With Let's Encrypt on the market, the barrier of entry for HTTPS is very low. If any sensitive data at all is sent through that connection, it's in your best interest.

For the record, that particular proxy is part of [ZScaler](https://www.zscaler.com/products/zscaler-overview) which is a security solution. Sadly, it includes HTTPS MITM, so the above is unlikely to solve the problem (but should be implemented anyway!). It's set up as an OS-level proxy - if that setting is possible to change, or override with Chrome's proxy settings, that would fix it. However, that's going to piss off network security!

If you can't do that, then your client is a SOL and should complain up the chain about the security solution breaking legitimate applications.

**Edit:** I looked around and found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/qCS_Aoajzww), which seems to claim that using SSL (that is, `wss:`) is enough. But that's from 2012 - perhaps before ZScaler was able to MITM all HTTPS traffic.

It should be possible to test whether `wss:` switch will work using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html - if it can *connect* then everything will work over `wss:`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reply to your answer. It helped a lot, thank you!